# Oman Visa for Russian Women

Tags: visas, female-travellers, russian-citizens, oman

My wife is Russian and carries a different family name in her Russian passport than mine. I carry a USA passport. she is under the age of 30 and we are planning on traveling to Oman together. What is required to get her a tourist visa for Oman?

Answer (score 8):

It may help you:

**Oman:**

Chinese, Russian and Ukrainian nationals may obtain visit visas following the same procedures provided that they are part of tourists groups arriving to the Sultanate through a local tourist agent or a hotel or **as a family**. In the case of groups, the number of females must not exceed the number of males. Source: [wikitravel.org](http://wikitravel.org/en/Oman)

It is OK for Russian wives who can prove their relationships with their husbands.

Comment: Would a marriage certificate original issued in the USA services as proof?

Comment: I am not sure as I am not from Oman embassy but rationally why not? It should be enough.

Comment: Arabs do not change the last name of wives after marriage, so this is common in Oman to have different last names for husband and wife. Regarding the marriage certificate, it is one of the few documents that are accepted everywhere as it is, no one can issue a local certificate marriage! unlike driving licenses for example.